# Make Eclipse let me set a breakpoint in my custom language code

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I've written a compiler that produces JVM bytecode for a custom language. The compiler emits line numbers and SMAP debug information as per JSR-45. When I use the generated class files inside Eclipse, I'm able to step into the source code and Eclipse displays it correctly. However, I'm unable to set breakpoints in it.

If I open the source files in Eclipse with the default text editor, all breakpoint menu options are disabled. If I open them using Java editor, they are enabled but simply don't work.

How can I convince Eclipse to let me set breakpoints in the code?

Comment: I suspect that you're going to have to write an Eclipse editor for your custom language.  You can use the Eclipse Java editor as a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of Java breakpoints is sadly connected to the JDT Java editor (using .java files with the built-in text editor disallows creating breakpoints).

However, if you know your compiler, you can create the required markers for breakpoints. See Section Breakpoints in the Eclipse Corner Article [How to Write an Eclipse Debugger?](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html) for details.